# Passing dynamic value from one ASP page to another using Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Guys I am trying to pass a variable from one page to another. Upon searching I found that either `QueryString` method is used or `Session` is used for passing variable. I don't like `QueryString` method as it displays data in URL which could be modified so I went for sessions.

Now I have added a `DataGridView` in asp which has a button in each row. Upon clicking this button, a session variable is created having the value of 1st column of the row in which the button was clicked and then it redirects to another page in which I am using this session variable.

Now the problem is, when I was using the Visual Studio debugger, this was working fine and the variable value kept changing according to the button click. But once I uploaded the site to hosting, the variable is created the first time I click the button in `DataGridView` but when I press the button again in different row, the variable value doesn't change. It remains constant, unless I press F5 in browser on the redirected page, only then the value gets updated.

I think the value gets stored in browser's cache and doesn't change until I force refresh the page. What should I do to solve this problem? is there any other way to pass variable other than the above two mentioned methods?

Code for creating session and redirecting :

```
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
string ticketid = item["ID"].Text;
Session["viewID"] = ticketid;
Response.Redirect("View.aspx");
```

Code for retrieving session :

```
String s = Session["viewID"] as String;
```

I would also like to avoid using cookies, many users have cookies disabled in their browsers so using cookies wont be optimal.

Comment: There definitely isn't anything wrong with storing values in session. It is the preferred method when passing data between pages. That said, your code looks fine to me. Try adding some logging so you can see what is happening on the production server.

Comment: I think the page is getting stored in your cache, try setting View.aspx to not cache and see if that helps

Comment: @PseudoNym01 Where do I change the settings so that View.aspx is not cached? in my browser or is there any code for this purpose?

Comment: Check out this link from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z852zf6b.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just saving the value in cache. I have to force turnoff the cache settings in ASP web application. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on button click event to store in cookie

**`Response.Cookies["viewID"].Value = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ticketid));`**

and you can get value using this code:

**Try this:-----**

**`String s =Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(Request.Cookies["viewID"].Value));`**

Sorry I forget .Value after Request.cookies["viewID"]

Comment: Generates the following error message :
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.HttpCookie'